# Synchronizing Gmail mail

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I have fetched all Gmail mail using JavaMail API Imap protocol and show them in table format but now the problem is how show delete them?
on click that mail has to be deleted, all connection using protocol is lost and I want to delete that mail.

Answer (score 0):

Once you lose the connection to the server, you're effectively operating in "disconnected" mode.  The JavaMail FAQ has pointers to more information about [how to handle disconnected mode with IMAP](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#disco).  Doing this well is a lot of work.

A simpler approach is to do your best to ensure the connection isn't lost unnecessarily, e.g., by calling Folder.getMessageCount at least every 30 minutes.  If you still lose the connection (which **will** happen sometimes),
you toss all your cached data, reconnect, and refresh the user's view.

If you only care about being able to delete messages that the user can see, you might be able to take an intermediate approach.  You could save the UID of all messages (and the UIDVALIDITY of the Folder) and when the connection is lost you would reconnect and [get the Message objects for all messages based on UID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessagesByUID-long:A-).  Then you would be able to delete the message, if it still exists on the server.

Comment: Thanku sir! for help. what I was thinking like on message which I want to delete I will send the date of that mail and in IMAP code I will make that mails flag delete enable

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Suppose I lost the connection with gmail server then on click I will transfer the date and exact time the mail I received, I will establish the connection again but this time only the mail with same time and date will be fetched and delete Flag will be enabled for that mail hence the mail will get deleted.

Comment: I want to implement Mail server API in my project. Every user should able to make their email id like xyz@xyz.com and can send mail to any server like google, yahoo etc. which mail server API I use. I explored Apache James, will it be suitable for this?

Comment: Date and time is not unique.  That's why you need to use the message UID.

Comment: If you want to run your own mail server, there are a wide variety of choices, free and paid.  Apache James is one choice.  Developing requirements and doing a full evaluation of the choices is well beyond what can be done at stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanku sir for help